# Creating a type with a variable number of members

Tags: c++, templates

Normally, when writing a `Vector` type, I do something like the following:

```
template <typename Type>
struct Vector2{
    Type x;
    Type y;
};
```

...and then repeat for `Vector3`, `Vector4` and so on.

This made me wonder, is there a better way to do this? For example, by expressing the number of members this type must have through sometime like a template. I'm not sure how the compiler would know how each member would be named, but just wanted to check in case I'm missing a wonderful trick.

Comment: Usually you would store an array and forget about naming the elements.

Comment: Naming is indeed the problem why it is very hard to create classes programatically. But `std::tuple` works wonders here.

Comment: @pmr I've not had any experience with `std::tuple` yet, are you able to show me what you mean? It sounds promising.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you, that is a valid alternative.

Comment: You mean like [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)?

Comment: @OMGtechy A tuple is just an array that supports different types. Or better: an array is a tuple where all types are the same.

Comment: @pmr Thank you for that. So, considering that all types within each `Vector` instantiation are to be the same, would I be write in saying I'd be better off with an array?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thank you, pmr also suggested this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your types are the same `std::array` can be helpful. You can then
write your accessor functions as free-functions and get static
assertions when the size is out of bounds. If your types are
different, you could use `std::tuple` instead of `std::array`.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

namespace X {

template<typename T>
using Vector2 = std::array<T, 2>;

template<typename T>
using Vector3 = std::array<T, 3>;

// named accessors, you might want to make the accepted parameter more
// specific, e.g. std::array<T,I>
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) x(T&& t) { return std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(t)); }
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) y(T&& t) { return std::get<1>(std::forward<T>(t)); }
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) z(T&& t) { return std::get<2>(std::forward<T>(t)); }

}

int main()
{
  X::Vector2<int> v = {1, 2};
  // you can use [] syntax
  std::cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << std::endl;
  // or named access
  X::x(v) = 2;
  X::z(v); // static assertion triggered
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, once I understand the answer I shall accept it (assuming it is correct and a better one doesn't appear)